# Ignoring 32 bit third party dll error in 64 bit assembly in .NET C#

Tags: c#, .net

In my legacy C# WPF + WinForms 64 bit application, I use a third party 32 bit dll which throws the following exception as expected

> Caused by: Could not load file or assembly 'XYZ, Version=4.2.100.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abf8346bff9e0a32' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

Now if this application is run via Visual Studio 2015, this exception is thrown but it continues to run the application but when it is run via Visual Studio 2017 it refuses to run.

How Visual Studio 2015 continues to run the application even after the exception is thrown?

I do not own the source code of the third party dll so I most likely have to live with the 32 bit version. Given the circumstances, how do I ignore this exception but continue running this application via Visual Studio 2017 as in the case of Visual Studio 2015?

I understand that 32 bit and 64 bit dlls can't be mixed in one process but I have been wondering, given the same setup, how VS 2015 allowed it to run whereas VS 2017 refused to run. Any pointers on this?

Comment: This exception is generated when the just-in-time compiler loads the DLL.  Exactly when that happens is unpredictable, all that you know is that it happens at *some* time before the code start running.  It will happen earlier in the Release build than the Debug build for example.  That makes the proper placement of a try/catch unpredictable as well.  There is certainly a proper way to address this, when you know for a fact that you use a library that you can never actually get loaded then you need to remove it.

Comment: @HansPassant Unfortunately removing the dll is not an option for me.

Comment: @Rajaraman you can't mix 32 bit and 64 bit dll in one process, you might need to host the third party dll in a 32 bit process, and use some crossing process calls to invoke it. this is a lot of work, before doing it, make sure third party doesn't provide 64 bit or anycpu version.

Comment: Change your application to be 32-bit, that should get rid of the problem.

Comment: @VictorXie Yes, getting the 64 bit from third party is the fall back option but I want to understand how VS 2015 allowed it with the same setup. I have edited my question to include this.

Comment: It might have opted to revert to running it in 32-bit when that exception crops up, or somehow it made your program catch that exception and simply continue, it certainly didn't *use* that dll in a 64-bit world.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Exactly, why VS 2017 somehow could not catch the exception and allowed it to run similar to VS 2015. Do I have to explicitly enable any setting for this is my core question?

Comment: Remove the assembly. No matter what Visual Studio did, it did not make it possible to load and run a 32-bit assembly into a 64-bit process. So either it forced your application into 32-bit, in which case you can do that yourself, or it ignored the problem with loading the assembly, and then you can do *that* yourself. Either way you still cannot load a 32-bit assembly into a 64-bit process.